# Why doesn't the Terminator rev-9 keep its two skeletons split during fights?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-dark-fate

*Terminator: Dark Fate* introduces the Terminator rev-9, part regular Terminator, part shapeshifting alloy. Notably, it can separate said two parts, in order to have not one, but *two* deadly Terminators after its target.

However, in some of the fights (at least the last one), it splits, then merges itself back. I can understand the need to merge after the fight (go back into infiltration unnoticed), but why during a fight? Especially, it seems that both forms are combat-ready and independent.

Why not keep split in two, keeping the good guys in separate fights to increase the chances of getting to Daniella?

Out-of-universe, it might make for a harder fight to process (by filmmakers and viewers), but what about in-universe? Is it a technical limitation of the rev-9?

Comment: Using simple deductive reasoning, I might suggest it would be due to physical integrity issues. Two Terminators making up the mass of one would be structurally weaker in a fight than a regular Terminator. While tactically advantageous; physically, they would be weaker and easier to defeat.

Comment: @Ben I agree that it's the most plausible explanation, but would appreciate some confirmation on it. Pros and cons of duplications aren't made clear in the movie (cons, especially).

Comment: It is far more vulnerable when split. If you watch the movie, Arnold is able to throw the endoskeleton like a rag doll and that human terminator protecting Dani can easily slash the liquid metal portion. Thing is, and you will notice it with this terminator's exterior part,  that it is not the same standalone liquid metal terminator model as T-1000. It is like comparing a cinder block that breaks off into dust vs. jello. The liquid metal seemed to be more susceptible to breaking apart and evaporating. 

How in the world did a spinning turbine break off the liquid metal portion?

Comment: Continuing off my previous comment, it seems as if the liquid metal portion lacked integrity when compared to Robert Patrick's model. I highly doubt a turbine would have been able wreck the exterior. The only way to keep liquid metal from "re-attracting" is to change the composition. Unless some other metal was melted down and it changed the composition of the outer exterior, as it did with the Rev 9 caught in the blades, you would have seen it gather and come back after them.